# I wanted to check if a column value is not a decimal in Hive

Tags: hive, hiveql

I have a table with columns like

```
S.No Product Quantity
 1  Chair   1
 2  Table   3
 3  Fan     2.4
```

I wanted to have a check to see if quantity column is not negative. If it's negative it should not return the row.
I want the result only first two rows 1 & 2
Please suggest me how to come up with the query in Hive which returns only not decimal values

Comment: Hi, please always try to accept the answer which helped you so that it is easy for others to refer the solution of the mentioned problem statement

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the most efficient way of doing it but this will get your job done.

```
select SNo, Product, Quantity from table_name
where Quantity=round(Quantity)
and Quantity>=0
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be another way to select the rows that only have numbers (no decimals or negative signs):

```
SELECT * 
FROM table
WHERE Quantity NOT RLIKE '[^0-9]'
```

Here, the `'[^0-9]'` checks if any value is not a digit. The `NOT RLIKE`  is a double negative and will return all the rows, except for the ones that contained something that was not a digit.

To run this on only the first two rows of the results of your dataset add:

```
WHERE S.No <=2
```

Comment: Have you noticed the `hive` and `hiveql` tags?

Comment: "I want the result only first two rows 1 & 2", I changed the answer to assume OP wants to test the first two rows of the dataset not just return the first two lines of output, thanks